# How to add a local file into a maven project?

Tags: file, maven, local

Hi I'm trying to use the tokenizer in OpenNLP to develop a maven project. It needs to load a local file, but I don't know how to add it into the project so that even when I launched the project in other machine it still works. Like below, the project need to load this local file, how should I configure the file to be added into the project?

```
InputStream modelIn;
    try {
        modelIn = new FileInputStream("E:\\en-token.bin");
        // Make sure the "en-token.bin" file is already in your local disk

        TokenizerModel model = null;
        try {
            model = new TokenizerModel(modelIn);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (modelIn != null) {
                try {
                    modelIn.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
        Tokenizer tokenizer = new TokenizerME(model);
        String tokens[] = tokenizer.tokenize(string);
        List<String> tokenResult = Arrays.asList(tokens);
        return tokenResult;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Is this a kind of Test resource file or which is needed during production? Should it be packaged into your jar/archive ?

Comment: It's the model for tokenizing words into seperate sections. I'll put the rest part of code here.

Comment: That means it should be part of the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such kind of files should be put into **src/main/resources** folder which will be packaged into jar file.

Comment: I put it into the resources but don't know how to package it into a jar file. It's still a .bin file now.

Comment: If you do a **mvn package** it will be packaged automatically into the jar file.

Comment: I ran this but showed not recognized as an internal or external command. Sorry I'm very new for Java stuff so it seems a bit complicated to package the file. But will continue trying other way to pack into jar